# How to find next AUTO_INCREMENT value of a table in MYSQL 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, auto-increment, mysql-8.0

I was using the query below to find the next AUTO_INCREMENT value of table in MYSQL 5.7

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLENAME'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE( );
```

But, the same query in MYSQL 8 is returning NULL. I have used above query in my application which works fine with MYSQL 5.7 but behaves strangely with MYSQL 8.

Can anyone suggest how to find next AUTO_INCREMENT value in MYSQL 8.

Also, if there is a common query which works in both (MYSQL 5.7 and 8) then it would be very helpful.

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation suggesting that this has changed in MYSQL 8. Are you sure the table has an auto-increment column?

Comment: See [Bug #91038 AUTO_INCREMENT does not increase automatically](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91038).

Comment: FWIW:  Your code should not be concerned with finding the current/next auto-increment value. Insert the row, then find the assigned value from your insert.  It sounds likely that you are doing something that will break under any meaningful level of concurrency.

Comment: See [5.1.7 Server System Variables::information_schema_stats_expiry](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_information_schema_stats_expiry). Check [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b21ee67940aca7816f528f8f9f527e58).

Comment: @wchiquito Thanks a lot for pointing me to correct direction. Your comment helped me. I am currently looking ways to permanently set value of system variable information_schema_stats_expiry to 0 so that every time i get latest auto increment number and not from cache. I tried to set variable value with `SET GLOBAL INFORMATION_SCHEMA_STATS_EXPIRY = 0;` it worked on that day but on second day i felt like value was again set back to its original value. I will try if `SET PERSIST INFORMATION_SCHEMA_STATS_EXPIRY = 0;` does trick.

Answer (score 2):

By default, MySQL 8.0 refreshes the `AUTO_INCREMENT` values only once every 86400 seconds (once a day). Execute the following statement to refresh the value manually per table before fetching the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value, in this case a table called `TABLENAME`.

```sql
ANALYZE TABLE `TABLENAME`;
```

This statement works in MySQL 5.6, 5.7, and 8.0.

You can then execute your statement as you were before.

```sql
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLENAME'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE( );
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use

```
ALTER TABLE %1
ADD COLUMN id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST;
```

to create column, then query

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLENAME'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE( );
```

should return correct value.

Comment: What's the rationale of adding a dummy second AUTO_INCREMENT column?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).